# Cursor is returning 0 count when query should be returning a row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my Databasehelper class function the cursor here is returning 0, while I checked the query in sqlite and it returns one row, also some same function for basic select query is also working fine.
Here is my code

```
    public ModelClass getDataInfo(String dis)
    {
    String audio, Arabic,  Eng,  Urdu, trans,desc;
    SQLiteDatabase mDataBase =this.getReadableDatabase();
    ModelClass data=new ModelClass(null,null,null,null,null,null);
    Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery("select * from TblDua dua inner join TblCure cure on dua.DuaId=cure.DuaId inner join TblDisease disease on disease.DiseaseId=cure.DiseaseId where disease.category='"+dis+"'",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i =cursor.getCount();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        desc = cursor.getString(1);
        Arabic = cursor.getString(2);
        Urdu = cursor.getString(3);
        Eng = cursor.getString(4);
        trans = cursor.getString(5);
        audio = cursor.getString(6);
        data=new ModelClass(desc,Arabic,Urdu,Eng,trans,audio);
        //data.add(new ModelClass(desc,Arabic,Urdu,Eng,trans,audio));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    close();
    return data;
    }
```

I've tried giving permissions in manifesto but same.

Comment: at which point is the cursos "returnin 0"? have you debugged your code?

Comment: can you post the db data? or can you verify whether that query returns any rows?

Comment: So `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false?

Comment: cursor.getCount() returns 0, therefore while loop doesn't start, but the query is fine I tested it on SQLite and it does return a row, but on android it's not returning any row. I'm guessing it's something with multiple innerjoins.